# If $ \ S : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ be a shear map with respect to the unit vector $ \ n \ $

Tags: linear-algebra

Select the correct options :

(1) If $ \ S : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ be a shear map with respect to the unit vector $ \ n \ $  , then $ \ S (x)=x \ $ for every $ \ x \perp n \ $

(2) If $ \ S : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ be a shear map with respect to the unit vector $ \ n \ $  , then $ \ || S (x)|| =||x|| \ $ for every $ \ x \perp n \ $

(3) If $ \ S : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ be a shear map with respect to the unit vector $ \ n \ $  , then $ \ S (x)=x \ $ for every $ \ x \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ $

**Answer:**

We know that a **shear map** shift a vector along a particular direction.

But I can not answer the above questions.

Can some one help me with atleast hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

In the basis $\{m_1,n,m_2\}$ with $m_1\perp n$ and $m_2\perp n,m_1$ we have that

$$T_S=\begin{bmatrix}1&k&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: So, $ S(x,y,z)=(x+ky,y,z) \ $.  Now what to do?

Comment: @MONJURALAM We have that for any $v=xm_1+zm_2 \perp n$  $S(x,0,z)=(x,0,z)$

Comment: Thus options $ (1) \ \ and \ (2) \ $ are true.

Comment: @MONJURALAM Yes since option 1 $\implies$ option 2.